# NunitTest a ConsoleOutput

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I'm trying to Nunit Test a method, where I'm asserting that I'm getting the correct output, but the problem is each time the code jumps into :

Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);

And appearently you can't redirect SetCursorPosition, So my question is:.." is there anyway I can unit test this method reasonably"

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        int xOffset = 84; 
        int yOffset = 3;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);
        Console.WriteLine("Events");

        string header = "| LogType         | Message      |          tagCollection |          Time |";

        Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);
        Console.WriteLine(header);

        Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', header.Length));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Status))
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);
            Console.WriteLine(Status);
        }

        foreach (string str in NotificationList)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```

Here is my test:

```
    [Test]
    public void NotificationDisplayer_inputTestString_ExpectedResult()
    {

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            Console.SetOut(sw);
            uutNotificationDisplayer.Execute();
            Assert.That(sw.ToString()), Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
        }
    }
```

Comment: why just not make a mock method of this one and make the offset value for y change? Because technically, that's what you're trying to verify here in your test. More than that, could you also give us your unit test please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does two things in one place which causes the problem.

You want to construct a string in your method and print it. They should be separated. The test case is interested if the string is constructed properly or not, not if the `Console.WriteLine` or `Console.SetCursorPosition` works properly. So let us separate the code like shown below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var messages = GetMessagesToPrint();
    Execute(84, 3, messages);
}

// Method for which you should write the test method on its output
private static List<string> GetMessagesToPrint()
{
    string header = "| LogType         | Message      |          tagCollection |          Time |";
    ...
    ...// actual list of string you want to construct.
    ...
    var messages = new List<string> {"Events", header, new string('-', header.Length)};
    return messages;
}

//This doesnt need a test method
public static void Execute(int xOffset, int yOffset, IEnumerable<string> messageToPrint)
{
    foreach (var message in messageToPrint)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(xOffset, yOffset++);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Then you can write unit test for GetMessagesToPrint and need not worry about the System.Console methods.